# How to send a mail using xampp in windows XP?

Tags: php

I am using XAMPP for localdevelopment.And I am using the mail() function for sending the mail.
But unfortunately it wont sent the mail.I am not using any SMTP server in local host.If I need to sent  mail what can I do?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problems with your space bar? :)

Comment: Exactly! Even though working on that very coool..

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your SMTP server details in your php.ini. Alternatively, you may use a mailer library like the [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: I tried that one.It displays the error only.This is the error `C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexample\Swift-4.0.6\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php  on line 406`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexample\Swift-4.0.6\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:406 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexample\Swift-4.0.6\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(299): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexample\Swift-4.0.6\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(107):

Comment: I guess you forgot to enable the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

As Maerlyn suggests, you can add the SMTP to your php.ini file. However thing to keep in mind is that if your SMTP server requires authentication or it requires POP before SMTP, php.ini cant help you with that. If your ISP has an SMTP server and you have configured your Outlook to use your ISP email account, it will authorize your IP (for some time) to send out emails through that SMTP server so the mail() function will work.

Comment: I am using the smtp.gmail.com.I am not sure is it correct or not.But I amusing this one.And also I think it needs the TLS verification.Some body suggest that http://www.projectpier.org/node/817

Comment: if you want to use Gmail, you will need to use something else besides the mail() function maybe PHPMailer? it has worked like a charm for me over the years with Gmail.